# No item found in pull request in visual studio team explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

Using VS 2017 15.4 with VSTS source control (GIT version control).
I am able to connect, push and pull with VSTS from Visual studio team explorer.
When i click the "Pull Requests" in VS team explorer it is not showing the Pull Requests created in VSTS which assigned to me or created by me and showing "You are not connected to a remote repository"

Please help

Comment: Try to call `devenv.exe /resetuserdata` command (devenv.exe is in Visual studio installation folder, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE`), then try again. If the issue still persist, try to repair the VS and try again.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot for that?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I having the exact same problem.

Comment: @maze_dk i haven't found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Goto TeamExplorer --> Manage connections and see weather you have connections for it, else try to add connection.

If you are having connections then go to repository settings and see remotes origin fetch and push url's are correct or not.